# Is this correct way to add the openid_shutdown_ack to the request

Tags: python, google-openid

I have extend the getMessage of AuthRequest in consumer.AuthRequest

This is the object i get. I removed the values before the added openid_shutdown_ack parameter

```
<openid.message.Message {...(<Symbol Bare namespace>, 'openid_shutdown_ack'): '2015-04-20', ('http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1', 'optional'): 'nickname,fullname,postcode,country,language,timezone', ('http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0', 'type.country'): 'http://axschema.org/contact/country/home', ('http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0', 'mode'): 'checkid_setup', ('http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0', 'type.timezone'): 'http://axschema.org/pref/timezone', ('http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0', 'required'): 'email', ('http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0', 'type.email'): 'http://axschema.org/contact/email'}>
```

this message will be converted to request.htmlMarkup(realm, redirect_to) and send to google.

Is this a correct way to send this migration parameter to Google?

Answer (score 0):

As long as it contains a openid_shutdown_ack field as query parameter with value 2015-04-20 it should be fine.

Verifying if the change is working as intended is straightforward, if you continue to see the warning message there is an issue with your implementation (just for reference of intended behavior, imdb.com is currently implementing this properly -- note that when you try to login with a Google account no warning message is shown).

Hope that helps!